# What Tools and Extensions are Critical for Magento Development?

Tags: php, magento, tooling

We're building a nice little community of Magento experts here.  I'm curious what Magento extensions and other software tools (IDEs, editors, etc.) everyone is using to help with their development projects?

Both free and commercial tools are more than welcome.

Comment: Already there are some great suggestions here. Can everyone please provide links with them all?

Comment: Adding to clockworkgeek's suggestion, people with low rep can't add links, so if old timers could edit up their posts that'd be great.

Comment: May I add Magicento here
http://magicento.com/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Personal developer surely need

- PHP IDE ([Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/products/studio/), [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/))
- LAMP/WAMP on personal development machine
- [X-Debug](http://www.xdebug.org/) as a must
- MySQL client ([HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/))
- Firefox + FireBug as main browser; Safari 4/5, Chrome, Opera 10, IE 6/7/8/9
- SSH Client ([PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html))
- FTP Client and File manager over SSH ([WinSCP](http://winscp.net/))
- Manuals for PHP, MySQL, Javascript and Prototype
- Bug tracking system ([Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/))
- [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) to keep own revisions and be in touch with future Magento release from at magentocommerce.com
- [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) for SVN better sources comparison
- Image Viewer ([XnView](http://www.xnview.com/)) to work with images from time to time
- Password keeper ([PwSafe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/)) for all hostings, mysqls and other passwords
- Internet access for Q&A, Magento forums and tutorials

No custom extensions are really necessary, X-Debug and own experience help a lot. For beginners [Commerce Bug](http://store.alanstorm.com/products/commerce-bug) will be helpful.

Comment: as you are listing common web dev tools then don't forget fiddler for debugging http requests

Comment: firebug is enough, fiddler is needed rarely

Comment: firebug can't debug http calls from flash

Comment: What's vital to one person might be noise to another, it it's always interesting to hear what other people are doing.

Comment: Working with Magento you rarely need to debug flash http requests, that's why I said that fiddler is not really needed

Comment: +1 for Xdebug being essential

Comment: If you use Xdebug ( and you must :) you will love 'Easy Xdebug' extension for FF or 'Xdebug Helper' for chrom ... those make easy to start debug on one particular page without start from index.php

Comment: Here is a list of must-have extensions & techniques compilation for Magento debugging & development - http://dploy.in/2012/magento-debugging-and-development/ (its a part of every project at our web agency)

Comment: here is another one https://github.com/ecoco/magento_profiler
maybe you can add it to your answer

Answer (score 8):

This list keeps getting longer the more I think about it!

**Tools**

- Netbeans 6.9 w/ [ScratchPad](http://code.google.com/p/netbeans-scratchpad-plugin/), [TailFile](http://sites.google.com/site/roguexz2/netbeans), [Scan On Demand](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand) and [Path Tools](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=676) plugins
- XAMPP w/ Xdebug (Phpmyadmin of course)
- [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com)
- SVN  (I know, should be on GIT, but just haven't gotten there yet)
- PHPUnit & [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
- [Assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com) for team collaboration, issue and time tracking, etc
- Filezilla & PuTTY
- VMWare for browser compatibility and deployment target OS testing
- Chrome w/ [Pendule](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbkffbkamcejhkcaocmkdeiiccpmjfdi) and Developer Tools (preferred for CSS and JS debugging)
- Firefox w/ FireBug, [FirePHP](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-firephp-extension/), [FireDiff](http://www.incaseofstairs.com/firediff/), [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/), [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/), [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), etc.
- OpenOffice Calc for editing CSV because it actually respects the format (unlike other spreadsheet applications that won't be named...)
- [FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/)
- [RegExr Desktop](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/) (requires Adobe Air)

**Common Magento Extensions**

- [CommerceBug](http://store.alanstorm.com/products/commerce-bug)

  the following extensions are available through Magento-connect
- HM_DeveloperToolbar
- ModuleCreator
- Fontis_Recaptcha
- Fontis_Australia
- Tangkoko_CmsSearch
- TBT_Enhancedgrid and TBT_MassRelater

  occassional use, but recommended:
- Unirgy_Giftcert and Unirgy_StoreLocator
- Yoast_Filter
- Netzarbeiter_GroupSwitcher

Answer (score 6):

[ack-grep](http://betterthangrep.com/)

[Commerce Bug](http://store.alanstorm.com/products/commerce-bug)

[MageTool](https://github.com/alistairstead/MageTool)

Comment: Wow, MageTool has come a long way since I saw it last.  Need to get into that, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 6):

- [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) - I used Intellij Idea for Java development so this came naturally, The biggest thing I love about this that I have been wanting for PHP is conditional break points. Huge for Magento when you are trying to debug something in autoload or something where there are hundreds of calls to a method.
- [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) - I used to use this before PhpStorm, I feel its much faster to learn and configure then Eclipse, I know most people I work with use Ecplise and SVN I think sucks in it compared to these last two and other tools such as find usages and what not
- I'm on a Mac but on 10.5 so I used Entropy php, but when others in on Snow Leopard come to work I suggest they use [Mamp Pro](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/index.html), very powerful for local environment setup. Super quick to get virtual hosts and what not setup, can even use multiple ports and everything.
- [Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/) - For database management
- [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) for quick edits and other types of projects
- [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) for quick ftp if not using command line, probably the best FTP client ever created

Comment: ooh, conditional breakpoints!  That's the one feature that I really miss in NetBeans... that could tip me over the edge to PhpStorm!

Answer (score 4):

[JetBrains PHP Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/index.html) 2.0 EAP Builds (They must of named their IDE after you Alan ;) )

[Zend Server CE /w Zend Debugger](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/)

[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

Comment: A bunch of people at the Mallorca conference mentioned PHP Storm as an IDE worth paying attention to.

Comment: So far I've been pretty happy with it - It's not as "light weight" as they say it is (Java based after all) and I wish the code completion would pick up on Magento's way of initializing some models and such, anyone coming from NetBeans should feel at home. I'm a huge fan of JetBrains ReSharpper, the insight it provides helped me learn to code better c#, hoping phpStorm will do the same.

Answer (score 4):

- [git](http://git-scm.com/) for versioning
- [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) for deployment
- [eclipse pdt](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr1) (tried phpstorm, ranked out due poor project management and
  non-existent remote editing capabilities)
- [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/)
- [zend ce , apc, memcached](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/)
- [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) for bugtracking with git integration

Comment: Thanks Anton, this is somewhat off-topic, but could you post any information you have from your experience using Capistrano and specifically setting it up for Magento?

Comment: i made my own cap config file that only uses the ssh push part form capistrano and uses git for deployment so not a really capistrano way to do things but a good wrapper for executing commands over ssh

Answer (score 3):

Linux, vim, and custom command line tools to make life easy. Whenever possible, when making changes (like adding model override XML, for instance), I prefer to create a command line tool to do it for me. vim is nice because it is on darn near every server ever, so debugging remotely is about as comfortable as locally. As for linux, the idea of developing without ack/grep and a proper shell is just too much to bear.

Comment: If you're using vim be sure to checkout ctags: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/.  Vital for source navigation.

Comment: Great tool, thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 2):

[Commerce Bug](http://store.alanstorm.com/products/commerce-bug) extension from Allan Storm :-)

[Aptana/Eclipse for IDE](http://aptana.com/)

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) for quick edits

[Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/)

Answer (score 2):

**Development**

Local setup is [MacBook](http://www.apple.com/store/), [Coda](http://panic.com/coda), [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/), [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) to manage MySQL, Git or SVN depending on project.

Staging area is on my development server (LAMP) or on client-provided hosting.

For starting projects I have a base template and module set that includes most of what I put into projects.

**Modules**

Just started using Alan's Commerce Bug.  I plan on looking into MageTool soon.

I use Unirgy's [Gift Cert](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Unirgy/extension/751/unirgy_giftcert) and [Store Locator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Unirgy/extension/956/google-maps-store-locator) often.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Studio or EditPlus

Subversion/svnmerge.py

PHPDoc

PHPUnit

Jira/Confluence for task/bug tracking and project specifications

You can see how to work with Magento using ZendStudio here, in [Magento Webinars Archive](http://www.magentocommerce.com/media/webinars/magento-developer-solutions-series-best-practices-for-magento-development/view)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/) on Ubuntu for a while now and love it. Combining a powerful IDE and command line tools (grep, etc...) has my vote.

On a side note, I've been working on [a Magento extension named "Advanced Developer Tools"](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/jonathan.dh/extension/6604/dhmedia_devel).  I use it (a lot!) to get info about blocks and edit XML and PHTML files by clicking on blocks.  It's still beta though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Commerce Bug by Alan Storm is a Must for all developers.
2. Developer Toolbar  by MGT is another very good tool for Magento analysis.
3. Netbeans/PHP Storm IDE is recommended.
4. Git.
5. LAMP/WAMP.
6. PhpMyAdmin/ PHPMiniAdmin.
7. Mage::log and exception Log effective use.
8. Magento Path Hints.
9. New Relic.
10. SQL query log by modifying PDO file.
11. Module that displays what all blocks delivered from Cache.
12. Inbuilt Magento Profiler.