# Vim plugin for magento

Tags: magento

Is there any vim plugin available for auto suggestion of magento classes,functions? or is there any workaround available to achieve this?

Comment: Possibly already answered in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609010/what-tools-and-extensions-are-critical-for-magento-development](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4609010/4715590).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think ctags will help me

Comment: Was going to suggest the same link clockwork. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd take a look at ctags.  I haven't used it extensively myself, but I know that vi/vim was one of the earliest programs you leverage ctags support for code navigation.  My guess would be there's a way to use your `tags` file as a source for VIm autocomplete.