# What are the command line tool for Magento?

Tags: magento

I find a Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609010/what-tools-and-extensions-are-critical-for-magento-development) but I am looking for command line tool for Magento  development tools like Drupal have Drush and Drupal console to clear cache or create module or config.

Is there any similar tool for Magento ?

Comment: Magento 1 or Magento 2?

Comment: anyone but point is to speed up development

Comment: Magento 2 comes with it's own set of command line tools (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands.html) & Magento 1, you'd probably be best with something like n98-magerun (https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)